# Shell (bash) snmpset script tells Error in packet WrongLength

Tags: bash, shell, debian, snmp

Hi i have written the bash script for downloading configuration from switches and save it to TFTP server.

```
snmpset -v 2c -c Zaloznik 192.168.50.22 1.3.6.1.4.1.1991.1.1.2.1.6.0 s test_skript.cfg 1.3.6.1.4.1.1991.1.1.2.1.66.0 x C0A846D2 1.3.6.1.4.1.1991.1.1.2.1.9.0 i 22 >> /dev/null;
```

But it always tell me this:

> Error in packet. Reason: wrongLength (The set value has an illegal
>   length from what the agent expects) Failed object:
>   iso.3.6.1.4.1.1991.1.1.2.1.66.0

C0A846D2 is a HEX format of ip 192.168.70.210.

Don't you know how to fix it ? Please help, i have tried many combinations and nothing working.
Thanks.

Comment: `1.3.6.1.4.1.1991.1.1.2.1.66` has the type of `InetAddress`, http://www.circitor.fr/Mibs/Html/F/FOUNDRY-SN-AGENT-MIB.php which in turn is a OCTET STRING, http://www.circitor.fr/Mibs/Html/I/INET-ADDRESS-MIB.php#InetAddress Can you try to use `s "C0A846D2"` instead?

Comment: I have tried that and nope its still the same

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem solved, there was a problem with switches that want to have an info about
type of ip address (ipv4 or ipv6), then ip address of tftp, file name and after that he can send config files to tftp.

So i have to add another snmp OID (ip address type) into the script and then it works.